# readinessProbe for rethinkdb on k8s

Tags: kubernetes, rethinkdb

I'm surprised that the rethinkdb docker image doesn't come with examples for readinessProbe

Has anyone come up with an easy readinessProbe command using the rethinkdb docker image?

I only want to connect to the pod once the service is ready. Right now I'm falling back to having my k8s pod try to connect, crash if it cant, and have k8s restart the pod until this works.

Thats O.K. for deployment ...

But for development purposes I need to know when the db is truly ready as part of my testing harness.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example rethinkDB k8s config on GitHub [here](https://github.com/rosskukulinski/kubernetes-rethinkdb-cluster/blob/master/rethinkdb-quickstart.yml). In its [readinessProbe script](https://github.com/rosskukulinski/kubernetes-rethinkdb-cluster/blob/master/image/ready-probe.sh), it simply curl the app at 8080.

Comment: Ah, thats helpful. I should've realized you could just hit the admin console port to check readiness. FWIW instead of using a custom image I just used an `httpGet` check on that port like so: `
            "readinessProbe": {
              "initialDelaySeconds": 15,
              "timeoutSeconds": 3,
              "periodSeconds": 5,
              "successThreshold": 1,
              "failureThreshold": 3,
              "httpGet": {
                "path": "/",
                "port": 8080,
                "host": "localhost"
              }
            },
`